# Is it possible for BrowserMob Proxy to capture HAR at specific intervals while Selenium (Python bindings) runs?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, browsermob-proxy, browsermob

I'm trying to capture these events while navigating through the website and validate them against what events I'm expecting. I'm not even sure if BrowserMob Proxy + Selenium is even the right approach. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my problem is Selenium-wire

Then you can use the built-in requests functionality to loop through the requests.

```
  def event_checker(driver):
    event_list = []  # Initialize event list
    time.sleep(9)  # Wait for the request
    for request in driver.requests:  # Iterate through network requests
            query = request.querystring.replace('&', ' ')  # Replace ampersand with space
            query = query.split()  # Split on space into a list of requests
            for items in query:  # Iterate through items in query
                if "events" in items:  # If the word "events" is in an item
                    items = items.replace('%3D', '=')  # Replace unicode '=' with '='
                    items = items.replace('%2C', ' ')  # Replace unicode ',' with space
                    items = items.replace('%3A', ':')  # Replace unicode ':' with ':'
                    items = items.split()  # Split on space into a list of events
                    for e in items:  # Iterate through the list of events
                        if "events=" in e:  # Strip "events=" label
                            e = e.replace('events=', '')
                        event_list.append(e)  # Append the event to the event list
    return event_list  # Return the page title and event list
```